# stack positioned fill while rotated

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to implement a rotated by 90 degrees container that will fill the space available inside a Stack? When I try to set the size of the child of the rotated widget it seems like it is still being limited by the parent widget. I would like to know if there is someway to make it work.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      // something with size to define the size of the stack
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        height: 600,
        width: 300,
      ),
      Positioned(
        child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return SizedBox(
            width: constraints.maxHeight,
            height: constraints.maxWidth,
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: math.pi / 2,
              // this should have height equal to constraints.maxWidth
              // and width equal to constraints.maxHeight
              // but the height is equal to constraints.maxWidth
              // and the width as well
              child: Container(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by using an `OverflowBox` instead of a `SizedBox`

See difference between a `SizedBox` and `OverflowBox` below:

**SizedBox**

> A box with a specified size.
>
> If given a child, this widget forces its child to have a specific width and/or height (assuming values are permitted by this widget's parent).

**OverflowBox**

> A widget that imposes different constraints on its child than it gets from its parent, possibly allowing the child to overflow the parent.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You welcome. You can mark the answer correct so others can see the relevance

Answer (score 0):

I just figured there is a widget called OverflowBox that can be used to get this behavior. I swapped the SizedBox with a OverflowBox widget and things started to work as expected.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      // something with size to define the size of the stack
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        height: 600,
        width: 300,
      ),
      Positioned(
        child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return OverflowBox(
            maxWidth: constraints.maxHeight,
            maxHeight: constraints.maxWidth,
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: math.pi / 2,
              // has the expected size
              child: Container(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: after posting I searched some more on google and found the solution. yes, it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: _rotateAngel,
  child: _yourChildWidget());
```